# Google places api windows phone 8.1

Tags: google-maps-api-3, windows-phone-8.1

I have the following code, trying to find nearby carwashes. In browser I get the respond, but in programm I catch the exeption there 'string washesResults =  await carclient.GetStringAsync(washesString);' It seems like I don't get respond from google. Which Key do I need for my app? I used the key for web.

```
string washesString = "https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/nearbysearch/json?location=" + latitude + "," + longitude + " &radius=2000&types=car_wash&key="my key";

            HttpClient carclient = new HttpClient();
            string washesResults =  await carclient.GetStringAsync(washesString);

            dynamic JsonRespond = JObject.Parse(washesResults);
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you should use the server key and set the range of your users' ip address as allowed IPs. or set it to 0.0.0.0/0 to allow all users.

You can not use a web key for your mobile app because they do not have the Referrers address.

Comment: It's not working. I get exeption with the server key also. My request is valid, as it's been tested there http://jsonformatter.curiousconcept.com/